# Can anyone let me know What is encoding format of attached screen shot?

Tags: php, string, email, encoding

I am forwarding email from server to php file with script. when I get any special chars, I have string in format which is given in screen shot.

I am doing all in PHP.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: where is your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "=C2=A0" in MIME encoded, quoted-printable text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774471/what-is-c2-a0-in-mime-encoded-quoted-printable-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's UTF-8 encoded as [Quoted-Printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).

Comment: Thanks man!, you saved my many hours..

Comment: When i try to save it into database it saves as ??????. Can you help me how i can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mb_detect_encoding`  function from php.

[Read more about this here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

You can also retrieve data from a file to check the encoding. (like your stored emails).

Comment: According to documentation it can detect ASCII using `auto`

Comment: ASCII  is the output

Comment: It doesn't really detect 8 bit ascii vs 7 bit. Either way, this is quoted printable which is the format used for emails.

Comment: $a = chr(254)."2017 Dec 10\n=E0=B8=AA=E0=B8=A7=E0=B8=B1=E0=B8=AA=E0=10=B8=A3=E0=B8=B1=E0=B8=9A"; echo mb_detect_encoding($a,"auto");

Comment: Here is the best reference I can find on the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629938/how-to-detect-cp437-using-php

Comment: The 7 bit works, the 8 bit doesn't. This is relevant if you need to encode emails. If 7bit there's no need to encode, but if it is 8 bit than you need to usually use quoted printable, or base64.